# Reference Static Resources or Documents with direct link and no login to system

Tags: javascript, css, static-resources, document

Is there a way to access static resources or documents without being logged into the system. So if the file in not marked as "Internal Use Only", can I provide a direct link to it for others to access without login in?

My concern is mostly with a css file that I would like to use but the way things are set up, user will usually not be logged into Salesforce and the entire css will be gone from the site.

Here is the example of it only working if I am logged in:

https://ca7.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0067K000119noi6'>

So is there a way to embed an org id into the link so that it references the correct content from correct org?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try Salesforce Content?
With Salesforce Content, you will able to access documents outside the salesforce.
Static Resources can be accessed from Sites developed with Visualforce.

For more info on Salesforce Content.
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=content_about.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, unfortunately the does not work because the link that Libraries provides is a URL to the page where the CSS file can be downloaded. That does not work because there is no direct download link that can be embedded into the head of an html document.